# Getting the name of an uploaded file in ie

Tags: javascript

I have a file upload button that users click on the upload a function and when they choose the files they upload the site. This is working beautifully and perfectly.

However, I have come across a bug with the file name in ie.In Chrome and Firefox I am able to use the form data and grab the file name out of that. But in ie, it seems to be grabbing the entire path and using that as the name. Is there any other way to grab the file name from an uploaded file? So that this can be consistent and truly just be the file name?

My code looks like this.

```
var file = $(this).prop("files")[0]; 
var form = new FormData($('input[name^="media"]'));

form.append("fileName", file.name);
```

The ie name for the file

```
C:UsersUsersNameFolderNameMoreComplicatedFolderNameFileDocumentName.docx
```

and in every other browser it grabs the file name as

```
FileDocumentName.docx
```

Comment: Is the output from IE exactly that (all the folder names joined together) or are you missing some backslashes that are accidentally being escaped? Windows file paths use backslashes instead of forward slashes.

Comment: @FelixGuo, It is exactly as posted above. Otherwise I would be splitting it at the slashes to just grab the name. I'm not escaping anything, just grabbing the raw name.

Comment: could you specify which IE version causes the problem? I have checked IE10+ and it produces same output as other browsers

Comment: @pwolaq, we're using ie11

Comment: @zazvorniki could you try this example and see if it also alerts the whole path? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name

Comment: @pwolaq, I just tested it on two of our computers in the office and the entire file path is alerting out

Comment: Have you tried this: `document.getElementById("file").value.split('\\').pop()`? Btw, I've also checked your snippet in IE11 and it gives the clean file name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the whole form. Something like this..

```
var myForm = document.getElementByTagName('form');
var form = new FormData();

form.append("myForm", myForm);
```

Comment: The web service does not support sending the entire form. It needs to have the different data appended separately. This is not something I can change without having the backend person furious at me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you as long as you are using IE 10 and above. I have tested this on IE-11 and Chrome

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Get Name of uploaded file</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function fetchFileName(fileObjId) {

            var fileObj = document.getElementById(fileObjId);
            var txt = "";

            if ('files' in fileObj) {
                if (fileObj.files.length == 0) {
                    txt = "Select one or more files.";
                }
                else {
                    for(var i = 0; i < fileObj.files.length; i++) {

                        txt += "<br><strong>" + (i+1) + ". file</strong><br>";
                        var file = fileObj.files[i];

                        if ('name' in file) {
                            txt += "name: " + file.name + "<br>";
                        }
                        if ('size' in file) {
                            txt += "size: " + file.size + " bytes <br>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if(fileObj.value == "") {
                    txt += "Select one or more files.";
                }
                else {
                    txt += "The files property is not supported by your browser!";
                    txt  += "<br>The path of the selected file: " + fileObj.value;
                }
            }

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;

            return false;
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    File to Upload: <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" />&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Get File Name" onclick="return fetchFileName('uploadFile')" />

    <br/><br/>
    Output: <span id="demo"></span>

</body>

</html>
```

See this too - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_files.asp

Answer (score 0):

In internet explorer, you get the full path instead of just the file name.

You can use this regex `/[^\/\\]*$/` to match the desired output. Like:

```
var file = $(this).prop("files")[0]; 
var form = new FormData($('input[name^="media"]'));

// Use the regex here to get the desired output
var file_name = file.name.match(/[^\/\\]*$/)[0];

form.append("fileName", file_name);
```

Comment: If you look at the file name above you will see that there are no slashes

Comment: @zazvorniki did you try console.log() the `file.name` because there will be slashes in the output? Can you try again?

Comment: @zazvorniki which version of IE are you using?

Comment: Yes, when I console it out it is like the path above. No slashes. I'm in ie 11

Comment: @zazvorniki please post your form's HTML. What is there in `this`? Could you post more JS code as well?

Comment: The upload button is the only thing in the form. I don't know what other js to post. There is nothing that pertains to this. This takes place in a very isolated ajax call

Comment: @zazvorniki what is `this` in `$(this).prop("files")[0]; ` part of? Post the outer js of this...

Comment: The $(this) is the upload button. No, no update. It's still exhibiting the same behavior.

Comment: @zazvorniki I would still ask you to share the covering AJAX call here.. it is hard to get the reference here..